# Javascript Websocket check if no message received from server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

The web socket is successfully connecting and receiving data from the server. But I want to perform other actions when it stops getting data from the server or when the server is disconnected.

I tried setInterval and send a message to the server every second to check if its still up.

```
websocket.onmessage = (mcon) => {
    if(mcon !== null) {
       this.somemethod(mcon.data);
    } 
    else{
       // perform some action
    }          
};
```

The else "perform some action" should run if the no data received

Answer (score -1):

Create a state say `incomingData`, set state to true every time there is an incoming data from websocket. after you have received the data set the state to false.

when the `state` is false, perform other actions

off course, I would be able to provide a better answer if you would share the relevant code

Comment: Thanks for your idea, I added some code showing what I am trying to achieve. Using the state idea, may not work if you are receiving stream of data. When it receives the last data the state does not change.